# Cannot display images in Silverlight with URI sources

Tags: c#, silverlight

Hi I'm trying to learn Silverlight. So I got the Silverlight 4 in action book. The very first 'Hello World' app has me stumped. It's a little app that searches twitter for posts on silverlight and then displays them in a list box. I'm trying to bind a URI from an object to load an image for the item in the list box. That didn't work so I tried a static URI. That didn't work so I tried just making a basic image and setting the source in the XAML to a static URI. That showed the image in the preview window in VS2010 but still no image when I tried to debug. So I thought maybe there's something strange going on that's preventing silverlight from accessing external URIs but I quickly realized that that didn't make any sense because it was successfully getting information from twitter. Anyone have any idea what could be causing this problem? Thanks!

The XAML

```
   <ListBox x:Name="TweetList"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             Margin="12 41 12 12">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Margin="3"
                           Width="50"
                           Height="50"
                           Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"
                               FontSize="14"
                               Margin="3"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The C#

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TweetList.ItemsSource = _tweets;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Tweet> _tweets =
        new ObservableCollection<Tweet>();

    private void GetTweets_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, ea) =>
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ea.Result);
                XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

                var items = from item in doc.Descendants(ns + "entry")
                            select new Tweet()
                            {
                                Message = item.Element(ns + "title").Value,

                                Image = new Uri((
                                    from XElement xe in item.Descendants(ns + "link")
                                    where xe.Attribute("type").Value == "image/png"
                                    select xe.Attribute("href").Value
                                    ).First<string>()),
                            };

                foreach (Tweet t in items)
                {
                    _tweets.Add(t);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(t.Image.ToString());

                }
            };

        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=silverlight"));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the code you are using to access the image uri

Comment: what is the type of Image in `Image = new Uri`

Answer (score 0):

Check with straight forward uriaddress like`Image = new Uri("http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/482914861/fastcompanyred100_normal.jpg")`
If it succeeds then there may be a problem with the uri string you are trying to construct

Comment: I have tried that and it shows in the XAML preview but not when I actually try to debug.

Comment: have you used the full address or relative